# Write fast Common Lisp code

Tags: common-lisp

I'm not sure, if some weird things make my Code faster:

Is it normally better to use inbuilt operations or write new specialized functions, that do the same thing?
(for example a version of `#'map` only for vectors; my version is often faster without type declarations)

Should I define new (complicated) types to use them in declarations?
(for example a typed list)

Should I define slots directly to an object? (for example `px` and `py` for a 2-dimensional object, or is it ok to use one slot `pos` of type vector, that I could reuse it for other purposes)

Comment: You might be able to make your code faster in one particular implementation in some circumstances, but it might fare worse in another. Performance is implementation dependent. Perhaps you need to narrow down your question to a particular impementation and provide some code examples?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few parts to this but here is a quick braindump

### PROFILE!

Use a distribution of CL that has a profiler built in, I use sbcl for example http://www.sbcl.org/1.0/manual/Statistical-Profiler.html

The nice thing about the sbcl profiler is that once you have profiled a function, if you disassemble it, the machine code is annotated with statistics. This requires some knowledge of the target machine code.

Do not underestimate your implementation: They can have advanced type and flow analysis built in and are able to, for example, pick a vector only version of map when it makes sense.

Learn compiler macros: compiler macros can shadow functions this gives you a place to put extra optimizations based on the context of the form. IT does this without replacing the function so it can still be used in a higher order way.

### Learn Type declarations

I found this series of blog posts helped me understand this technique http://nklein.com/tags/optimization/page/2/ Read em all!

ONE MASSIVE NOTE: Don't ever lie to your compiler about a type. Type declarations are a way of telling your compiler you know what the type is the compiler doesn't even have to use them, and when it does it doesn't have to check you are giving it the correct thing.

### Unboxed data

Some implementations are able to unbox certain datatype in certain conditions. Sorry that is vague but you will need to read up for your implementation. For sbcl the 'sbcl internals' guide is very helpful.

For example:

```
(make-array 100 :element-type 'single-float :initial-element 0.0)
```

Can be stored as a contiguous block of memory in sbcl.

### PROFILE AGAIN (With realistic data)

I spent 3 hours writing a crazy compiler macro based n dimensional matrix multiplication routine and then tested it against a 1 line built in solution. For matricies below 5 dimensions there was not a big difference! For higher dimensions, yeah It rocked but that 'performance benefit' is purely academic because those code paths were never touched. Luckily I undertook the task for fun as I was asking the same question you are now.

### Algorithms

All the type specifiers in the world won't give you a 100times performance increase. This comes from better techniques. Read on the maths behind the problem, implements different helper functions that have different strengths and choose between them at runtime...then go back and use compiler macros to allow lisp to choose at compile time. OR specify the technique as a higher order functions, for example `make-hash-table` allows you to specify the hashing function and rehash sizes, this can be crucial in getting good performance at certain sizes.

### Know the limits of BigO

Algorithmic complexity means nothing if you loose all the of performance due to memory locality issues. Conversly sometime we can achieve superlinear performance characteristics if, by spliting the problem among cores, the reduced dataset now fits in the l2 cache.

BigO is a great metric but it isn't the end of the story. This is the reason assoc lists are a totally valid alternative to hash-tables for low numbers of keys and certain access profiles.

### Summary

There is a golden mantra I heard from somewhere in the lisp community that works so well:

`Make it Fast and then make it Fast`

If nothing else follow this. Chant it to yourself!

Get the program up and running quickly, in doing so you are more likely to spot the places where you can use a better technique or algorithm to get your several-orders-of-magnitude improvement. *Do* use CL's own functions first. Don't trade lisp's higher order nature too early by using macros, explore how far you can go with functions.

[Edit] More notes - the following is for sbcl

- Type definitions on struct slots are used for optimizing, type declarations for class slots are not.
- With regard to types, start with what makes the program easy to write and understand (Make it fast) and then look into access times if it is the bottleneck (make It Fast!)
- (slot-value x 'name) is very fast when name is known. Look at how with-slots uses symbol-macrolet to it's advantage

So to kinda directly answer your original question:

- built in first (also check libraries)
- does it make the problem easier to write and understand?
- use pos. By the time the performance of that indirection becomes and issue you will have found a dozen other ways to speed up the problem and the solution will be part of a wider optimization technique.